# Convert a C# code to Php using the DOTNET class

Tags: c#, php, interop

I'm trying to convert a C# code to php using DOTNET, I never use C# but a lot of php, so, I'm starting with a basic things, to se if usefull do the conversion, then have the next C# piece of code.

```
using System.Text;
class AES
{
    private byte[] _key;
    private byte[] _iv;
    public AES()
    {
    }
    public AES(string keyBase, string iv)
    {
        _key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyBase);
        _iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iv);
    }
}
```

then trying to convert just this piece, so I do the next in php

```
<?php
class Ejemplo{
    public function FunctionName($value = '')
    {
        echo "Hello world!...";
        //var_dump(\System\Text\Encoding::GetEncoding());
        $stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Text.Encoding");
        var_dump($stack);
   }
}
$eje = new Ejemplo();
$eje->FunctionName('nada');
?>
```

but in the line 
"$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Text.Encoding");"

Got this error "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to instantiate .Net object [CreateInstance] [0x80131513]",

then looking for the web, I see that need a full string with version and other things for dll refered to "System.Text.Encoding", my question is how to know the info for a dll, to can create a string like this

```
$csclass = new DOTNET("CSharpCOM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=beb607ae770f5750", "CSharpCOM.CSharpCOMClass");
```

but for my

```
$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Text.Encoding");
```

Or if someone know another way to do this. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "mscorlib", you do not need to provide the full assembly name with the culture and version, since this is one of the core assemblies of .net containing the most basic functions and is a fixed part of the .net runtime.

System.Text.Encoding is an abstract class. That is why you cannot create an instance of it. In the example, you want to use System.Text.ASCIIEncoding. So, create an instance of that class directly:

```
$encoding = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Text.ASCIIEncoding"); 
$bytes = $encoding->GetBytes("Hello World");
```

It should be noted that using .net assemblies from PHP with the help of "DOTNET" is limited, because it only allows you to instantiate classes. You cannot use static classes and enums, which means that some of the .net API is out of reach.

You can use the commercial [NetPhp](http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/content/netphp) library instead.

Alternatively, write the code in C# with a spefic narrow interface to be used from php.

Comment: Thanks, can U tell me how a can do this, after you answer change the line to "$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Text");" but got the same, i need to know how to do to know the complete string of the dll like this "CSharpCOM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=beb607ae770f5750"

Comment: "System.Text" is not a class but a namespace, you cannot create an instance of that, either. Create an instance of System.Text.ASCIIEncoding as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I use your example, but a got another fatal error "Fatal error: in D:\xampp\htdocs\dotnet\ejemplo.php on line 14", just like this, the line is "$bytes = $encoding->GetBytes("Hello World");", think that I going to use the .exe file from the compiler .cs :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe all the info you need to define the .dll is available on the .dll itself. Have you bothered to find your mscorlib.dll and viewing it's file details?

You might be able to find it under the folder {Drive}/Windows/assembly. You may need to install an Msoft util to view the assemblies properly. Once you can view the assemblies via the Msoft tool you'll be able to grab the Public Key Token and version to use in

```
$stack = new DOTNET("mscorlib", "System.Text.Encoding");
```

Comment: exactly that is I need to know, but dont know how read this info from the dll